# File Downloading issue, Complete file is not downloaded

Tags: asp.net

I have an application having front end in ASP.NET (VB.NET) and at back end is of Oracle. In oracle i have a procedure which generates files on two file servers (File Server A, File Server B). I have two server one is development server and the other one is client server. In my application i have a web page 'GenerateReport.aspx' which is used to generate report. On the basis of dates the backend procedure generate file on the File Server A and B. when i host the application on development server and download the generated file it is downloaded completely and when i host the application of client server and donwload the generated files only a part of file is downloaded (56KB of 97MB file). Code i use to download file is given below.

Private Sub DownloadFileClient(ByVal RemoteFilePath As String)

```
Try
    Dim File As System.IO.FileInfo
    File = New System.IO.FileInfo(RemoteFilePath)

    If File.Exists Then

        Response.Clear()

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & File.Name)

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", File.Length.ToString())

        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"

        Response.TransmitFile(File.FullName)

        Response.End()

    Else
        lblErrorMsg.Text = "Unable to Download"
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    lblErrorMsg.Text = "Unable to Download,check file path"
End Try
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flush the response stream before you call `Response.End()`.

Actually, unless there's other stuff you left out, you should Flush(), but don't bother calling `Response.End()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working but my question is why the same code is behaving differently on difference machines. is the .net framework is playing its role?

Comment: @Usman: I'm not certain what all could cause your discrepancy.  It could be things like different installed hotfixes, debug enabled/disabled, timing issues, etc.  In my experience, when working with streams, it's simply safer to *always* `Flush` at the end of your process.  It's become habit with me now.